# chrome extension - drive API scope drive.appdata throws an error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

in my manifest i have:

```
"oauth2":  {  
  "client_id": "****",  
  "scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" ]  
},
```

sending file to G-drive with XMLHttpRequest:

```
let file = 'testing testing testing';
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200)  console.log(xhr.responseText)              
        else console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
     console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(file);
```

This works fine. Response is listed in console, I can see ID of the file, if I visit G-drive I can see that file in main root.
**But I want to upload files to appData folder.**
If I change scope to :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

I get an error:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media 403
```

I was hoping that changing scope will be enough.
What do I need to change/add so this would work?
I'm guessing parents or somehow appdata folder ID, but not sure how to format it in header.
ps. please bear in mind that this is a chrome extension

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert): You are providing a string `file = "testing testing testing"` instead of providing a File resource, e.g `file = {title: "testing", mimeType: "text/plain", description: "testing", parents: [{id: "appDataFolder"}]}`, and then using `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(file))`. Also consider migrating to Drive API v3, instead of v2 you are using right now.

Comment: Also, in order to include the metadata, change the `uploadType` to `multipart`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko no, it doesn't work. metadata is stringified and just part of the uploaded file, and not parsed on the g-drive (to be folder name, file name etc). http://image.prntscr.com/image/e3d5d7f2985c47f7bf5b7c9861c03032.png also if I add appdata to scope, I'm getting 403 error... I added `multipart`

Comment: Read [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/multipart-upload),  the section `Sending a multipart upload request`, where it describes the format of the request's body you have to use to upload, both content and metadata (to include the appDataFolder as parent folder).

Comment: @IvánNokonoko can you post an example of that format in answer?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why the Drive API throws a 403 error response. Have you checked them [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded), see if one of them is possibly mentioning the issue?

Comment: @AL. I'm just getting errors, without any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is a sample code that should work. It creates a simple text file named "testing" with the description "testing" that contains only the plain text "testing testing testing" in the AppData folder. It was adapted from the example you can find in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
var filecontent = "testing testing testing";
var metadata = {
    title: "testing",
    mimeType: "text/plain",
    description: "testing",
    parents: [{id: "appDataFolder"}]
    };

var boundary = "----foo-bar";
var delimeter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

var multipartRequestBody = 
    delimeter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) + 
    delimeter + 
    'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + 
    filecontent + 
    close_delim;

xhr.onload = function(){
  console.log(xhr.response);
}

xhr.open("POST","https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary);

xhr.send(multipartRequestBody);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you!.   
I just successfully tested uploading to, and listing files from hidden folder. Works fine.  
I could just spill everything in root folder, but it's much safer  to have it hidden from users, eventually they will screw something up. That's why I needed this formatting, but I never worked with complex  `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @WolfWar Happy to help. I still think you should upgrade to Drive API v3. Let me know when your extension goes live.

Comment: I'll let you know :D